# Is this a way to filter O365 content search results by 'modified date'?

Tags: office365

Using O365 'Content Search' I need to find posts from 'Teams' chats which were modified in date I specified.

O365 has feature 'Content Search' under 'Office 365 Security & Compliance'. It allows grab content from all O365 data sources, like exchange, onedrive, sharepoint, etc.

Options I tried:

**(c:c)(kind=MicrosoftTeams)(date>2019-04-01)** filter returns all posts created after 01 April

**(c:c)(kind=MicrosoftTeams)(date>2019-04-01)(lastmodifiedtime=2019-03-09..2019-04-09)** filter also returns all posts created after 01 April, *lastmodifiedtime* simply ignored.

**(c:c)(kind=MicrosoftTeams)(date>2019-04-01)(received=2019-04-04..2019-04-04)** filter also returns all posts created after 01 April, *received* simply ignored.

Is there a property by which I can find ONLY modified 'Teams' chat posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a ticket in MS support, they returned to me with an answer: *It's not possible to get only changes for exported Teams IMs*, I can get IM modifications only in case **retention is enabled** for an account and **filter includes source IM** which was modified.